# Tkinter Checkbutton questions

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I want to build [a user interface like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6CEc.png)

the code is:

```
for ii in range(len(solutions)):
tk.Label(text=solutions[ii], bg="lightsalmon", fg="black", font=("times", 10), relief=tk.RIDGE, width=50, anchor="w").grid(row=ii+1,column=3, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
v = StringVar()
checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(mywindow, text='YES', onvalue='YES', variable=v, bg="red", fg="black", font=("times", 10), width=3, anchor="w", command=close_yes)
checkbutton1.deselect()
checkbutton1.grid(row=ii+1, column=4, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
checkbutton2 = Checkbutton(mywindow, text='NO', onvalue='NO', variable=v, bg="red", fg="black", font=("times", 10), width=3, anchor="w", command=close_no)
checkbutton2.deselect()
checkbutton2.grid(row=ii+1, column=5, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
```

the problem is I can only get the last checkbutton's value, can you help me to fix this problem? thank you very much!

Comment: You can use a list to hold the `StringVar` instances.  And is it better to use `Radiobutton` instead of `Checkbutton`?

Comment: I tried but doesn't work

Comment: v = [None] * len(solutions)
for ii in range(len(solutions)):
    v[ii] = StringVar()
    checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(mywindow, text='YES', onvalue='YES', variable=v[ii], bg="red", fg="black", font=("times", 10), width=3, anchor="w", command=close_yes)

Comment: cannot paste complete code because too long

Comment: How do you get the value of variable inside `close_yes()` and `close_no()` functions?

Comment: use v.get(), but now can only get the last one...

Comment: How can you call `v.get()` as `v` is now a list of `StringVar` based on the changes in your comment?

Comment: before changing to list, I use v.get(), I used v[ii].get(), but not work

Comment: You should not use `ii` inside the functions as it is assigned the last value of for loop.  Pass the correct index to the functions using lambda.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a list to holds the `StringVar` instances.  To access the correct instance of `StringVar` inside `close_yes()` and `close_no()` functions, you need to pass the correct index to them using lambda and default value of lambda argument:

```
def close_yes(i):
    print('close_yes:', i, v[i].get())

def close_no(i):
    print('close_no:', i, v[i].get())

...

v = [None] * len(solutions)  # list to hold the StringVar instances
for ii in range(len(solutions)):
    tk.Label(text=solutions[ii], bg="lightsalmon", fg="black", font=("times", 10), relief=tk.RIDGE,
             width=50, anchor="w").grid(row=ii+1,column=3, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
    v[ii] = tk.StringVar()
    checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(mywindow, text='YES', onvalue='YES', variable=v[ii],
                                  bg="red", fg="black", font=("times", 10), width=3, anchor="w",
                                  command=lambda i=ii: close_yes(i)) # use lambda to pass the correct index to callback
    checkbutton1.deselect()
    checkbutton1.grid(row=ii+1, column=4, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
    checkbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(mywindow, text='NO', onvalue='NO', variable=v[ii],
                                  bg="red", fg="black", font=("times", 10), width=3, anchor="w", 
                                  command=lambda i=ii: close_no(i))
    checkbutton2.deselect()
    checkbutton2.grid(row=ii+1, column=5, ipadx=0, ipady=0, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
```

Comment: omg, solved! Thank you very much! I stuck here for several days!